# python df into specific json format

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I need to create a json following this model from a df using python.
I tried to load this json into a df to find the correct layout but did not succeed.
Can anyone help me or at list give me some hints?

Thanks in advance

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "productId": 123456790,
      "quantaty": 10,
      "orderLine": "10",
      "buyerRef": "my ref"
    },
    {
      "productId": 123456791,
      "quantaty": 15,
      "orderLine": "20",
      "buyerRef": "my ref"
    }
  ],
  "costId": 109,
  "paymentMethod": "termTransferWire",
  "totalPriceTaxIncl": 1200,
  "deliveryAddressId": 218,
  "buyerOrderNumber": "Test",
  "documentationRequestedName": [
    "document 1",
    "document 2"
  ]
}
```

Comment: "did not succeed" is not a description of the issue. Please, provide your attempts and why were unsuccessful. Reference [tour] and [ask].

Comment: you want to convert this into a dataframe?

Comment: You've shown the data (JSON) that you have but you haven't stated what output you want or why you think using a DataFrame is relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
import pandas as pd

# Assuming you have a DataFrame df with the necessary columns
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'productId': [123456790, 123456791],
    'quantity': [10, 15],
    'orderLine': ['10', '20'],
    'buyerRef': ['my ref', 'my ref']
})

# Other information
cost_id = 109
payment_method = 'termTransferWire'
total_price_tax_incl = 1200
delivery_address_id = 218
buyer_order_number = 'Test'
documentation_requested_name = ['document 1', 'document 2']

# Convert DataFrame to JSON
json_data = {
    'products': [
        {
            'productId': row['productId'],
            'quantity': row['quantity'],
            'orderLine': row['orderLine'],
            'buyerRef': row['buyerRef']
        }
        for _, row in df.iterrows()
    ],
    'costId': cost_id,
    'paymentMethod': payment_method,
    'totalPriceTaxIncl': total_price_tax_incl,
    'deliveryAddressId': delivery_address_id,
    'buyerOrderNumber': buyer_order_number,
    'documentationRequestedName': documentation_requested_name
}

print(json_data)
```

The resulting json_data will be a dictionary following the structure you provided. You can use the json.dumps method to convert it to a JSON string if needed:
import json

```
json_string = json.dumps(json_data, indent=2)
print(json_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a dictionary of your json object

```
json_obj = {
"products": [
    {
    "productId": 123456790,
    "quantaty": 10,
    "orderLine": "10",
    "buyerRef": "my ref"
    },
    {
    "productId": 123456791,
    "quantaty": 15,
    "orderLine": "20",
    "buyerRef": "my ref"
    }
],
"costId": 109,
"paymentMethod": "termTransferWire",
"totalPriceTaxIncl": 1200,
"deliveryAddressId": 218,
"buyerOrderNumber": "Test",
"documentationRequestedName": [
    "document 1",
    "document 2"
]
}
```

Now in this dictionary, the json_obj.values can be considered as rows, and json_obj.keys can be considered as columns.

Create a new list for columns and rows

```
cols = list(json_obj.keys())
rows = list(json_obj.values())
```

Now, import the pandas library and create your data frame as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

pd_df = pd.DataFrame([rows], columns = cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = {
    "productId": [123456790, 123456791],
    "quantity": [10, 15],
    "orderLine": ["10", "20"],
    "buyerRef": ["my ref", "my ref"],
    "costId": [109, 109],
    "paymentMethod": ["termTransferWire", "termTransferWire"],
    "totalPriceTaxIncl": [1200, 1200],
    "deliveryAddressId": [218, 218],
    "buyerOrderNumber": ["Test", "Test"],
    "documentationRequestedName": [["document 1", "document 2"], ["document 1", "document 2"]]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert DataFrame to JSON
json_data = {
    "products": df[["productId", "quantity", "orderLine", "buyerRef"]].to_dict(orient="records"),
    "costId": int(df["costId"].iloc[0]),
    "paymentMethod": df["paymentMethod"].iloc[0],
    "totalPriceTaxIncl": int(df["totalPriceTaxIncl"].iloc[0]),
    "deliveryAddressId": int(df["deliveryAddressId"].iloc[0]),
    "buyerOrderNumber": df["buyerOrderNumber"].iloc[0],
    "documentationRequestedName": df["documentationRequestedName"].iloc[0]
}

# Convert dictionary to JSON
result_json = json.dumps(json_data, indent=2)
print(result_json)
```